# Exposing Rcpp modules

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am having some trouble working through the examples inside:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf

Specifically, section 2.2 where the author goes to expose a C++ class in RCPP and making it available to call in R.

I copied the code in to a new RCPP file and sourced it with no problem but got an error when I ran the following in R:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)
unif_module <- Module( "unif_module", getDynLib(fx_unif ) )
```

The error:

```
Error in getDynLib(fx_unif) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'getDynLib': Error: object 'fx_unif' not found
```

I then went though the other parts of the document where `getDynLib` is used and found that none of them initialized the arguments passed in to `getDynLib`. My question is what is `fx_unif`?

Thanks,

Update:

So following another example within the paper i tried:

```
inc = '
class Uniform {
public:
  Uniform(double min_, double max_) : min(min_), max(max_) {}
  NumericVector draw(int n) const {
    RNGScope scope;
    return runif( n, min, max );
  }
  double min, max;
};

double uniformRange( Uniform* w) {
  return w->max - w->min;
}
RCPP_MODULE(unif_module) {
  class_<Uniform>( "Uniform" )
  .constructor<double,double>()
  .field( "min", &Uniform::min )
  .field( "max", &Uniform::max )
  .method( "draw", &Uniform::draw )
  .method( "range", &uniformRange )
  ;
}
'

fx_unif = cxxfunction(signature(), plugin="Rcpp", include=inc)
```

error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="filef4028245a6f.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="filef4028245a6f.o"' had status 127 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB filef4028245a6f.cpp 2> filef4028245a6f.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

Comment: Rcpp modules really should be built within a package framework. Also, that vignette is presently undergoing a rewrite. Perhaps a more simple working example should be given as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549712/using-a-class-as-a-parameter-in-a-constructor-of-another-class